# Hotel - Single booking with multiple dependents in multiple rooms

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to list **dependents** of an individual guest. When booking an hotel, a guest may bring friend or child with them (dependents). However, when booking a room, only 3 people can be located in each room. So if a guest brings in 4 people with them, 2 dependents will stay in room 102, where as the other 3 in room 103. But they are under the same booking lets say booking id = 2002.

I am attempting an sql oracle query to display all dependents of a certain booking. Here is what I have attempted which works fine:

```
SELECT b.BOOKINGID,
       b.GUESTID,
       d.DEPENDANTID,
       d.FORENAME AS firstname,
       d.SURNAME AS lastname,
       br.FLOORNO,
       br.ROOMNO
FROM  BOOKING b
      LEFT JOIN BOOKINGDEPENDANT bd
      ON b.BOOKINGID = bd.BOOKINGID
      LEFT JOIN DEPENDANT d
      ON d.DEPENDANTID = bd.DEPENDANTID
      LEFT JOIN BOOKINGROOM br
      ON b.BOOKINGID = br.BOOKINGID
WHERE b.BOOKINGID = &BOOKINGID;
```

The issue I am facing with above query is that it is able to list all dependents, but it list them more than once when a booking is associated with multiple room.

for example booking 2002 uses room 102, and 103. thereby all dependents are associated with 103 including those staying in 103. same for 103.

Comment: @MooHa.....You need a way to see the DEPENDANT table associated with the BOOKINGROOM table. Something like DEPENDENT.ROOMID = BOOKINGROOM.ID.  Then LEFT JOIN BOOKINGROOM br
      ON d.ROOMID = br.ID

Comment: Would the dependents not be the occupants of all rooms associated with a given booking?

Comment: a person may book 2 separate rooms but under same bookingID. but it associated everyone with each rooms, so person x and y are both associated with room 102 and room 103 although y only stays in 103. so it prints dependants twice, for each rooms.

Comment: @MikeTWebb will it help if show u the ER ?

Comment: @MooHa...it would help

Comment: @MikeTWebb see edit of question

Comment: @MooHa.... According to your ER, since there is no relationship between a Dependant and a Room, so you will get the duplicated results in your query. The ER Suggests that DEPENDANTS are allowed to swap between rooms. If you want to constrain DEPENDANT to a room, then you would need to add ROOMID to BOOKINGDEPENDANT and map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to see the DEPENDANT table associated with the BOOKINGROOM table. 
Something like BOOKINGDEPENDENT.ROOMID = BOOKINGROOM.ID. Then join like this:

```
SELECT b.BOOKINGID,
       b.GUESTID,
       d.DEPENDANTID,
       d.FORENAME AS firstname,
       d.SURNAME AS lastname,
       br.FLOORNO,
       br.ROOMNO
FROM  BOOKING b
      LEFT JOIN BOOKINGDEPENDANT bd
      ON b.BOOKINGID = bd.BOOKINGID
      LEFT JOIN DEPENDANT d
      ON d.DEPENDANTID = bd.DEPENDANTID
      LEFT JOIN BOOKINGROOM br 
      ON br.ID = bd.ROOMID and ON br.BOOKINGID = b.BOOKINGID
WHERE b.BOOKINGID = &BOOKINGID;
```

Comment: @MooHa.... According to your ER, since there is no relationship between a Dependant and a Room, then you will get the duplicated results in your query. The ER Suggests that DEPENDANTS are allowed to swap between rooms. If you want to constrain DEPENDANT to a room, then you would need to add ROOMID to BOOKINGDEPENDANT and map those as in my answer above

Comment: But you are creating a relationship between a relationship (diamond) and an entity which is logically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need a mapping between the dependents and the rooms.  What you have is a mapping from a booking to the dependents and a separate mapping from the booking to the rooms.

Let me assume that you have a room id in `BookingDependant`.  If so, then the `from` clause would be:

```
FROM  BOOKING b
      LEFT JOIN BOOKINGDEPENDANT bd
      ON b.BOOKINGID = bd.BOOKINGID
      LEFT JOIN DEPENDANT d
      ON d.DEPENDANTID = bd.DEPENDANTID
      LEFT JOIN BOOKINGROOM br
      ON bd.BookingId = br.BOOKINGID and
         bd.BookingRoomId = br.BookingRoomId
```

This construct assumes that a single person doing a booking is in the `BookingDependent` table.

If you don'thave the roomid for each dependent, then remove the room from the query:

```
SELECT b.BOOKINGID, b.GUESTID, d.DEPENDANTID,
       d.FORENAME AS firstname, d.SURNAME AS lastname
FROM  BOOKING b
      LEFT JOIN BOOKINGDEPENDANT bd
      ON b.BOOKINGID = bd.BOOKINGID
      LEFT JOIN DEPENDANT d
      ON d.DEPENDANTID = bd.DEPENDANTID
WHERE b.BOOKINGID = &BOOKINGID;
```

You have no mapping from room to dependant, so there is no correct way to produce the results that you want.  If you want to make up an assignment, then you should probably ask another question, providing the layout of the tables and the rules for making up the assignment.

Comment: I have no "ROOM ID" in BOOKINGDEPENDENT. 

BookingDept (Booking ID {PK,FK}, DependantID {PK,FK})